# tkinter - resize text widget (sizegrip for text widget)

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to have a "sizegrip widget" that enables the user to resize a text widget.

Picture to illustrate: (I apologize for the bad gridding)

[image]

Is it possible to make the sizegrip widget resize a text widget instead of the root window?

Any alternative widget that fits my needs?

Comment: HIt should be possible, but probably won’t be easy. What do you expect to happen with the widgets below the text widget?

Comment: They would just move down. Imagine the text widget's high increase. I actually do not care about resizing the text widget's width. Actually now that I t hink about it, I would probably be better if you only could resize the text widget's height.

Comment: _”They would just move down”_ - what if there is no extra space? Why not just design the UI so that when you resize the window, the text widget grows?

Comment: They will be pushed down out of the view in the root window. Picture to illustrate what I am talking about: https://gyazo.com/a1760ffceb881d7f34aad1b69451f109

Comment: I guess you could do that using `bind` but would be rather complex imo. As in you could put your `Text` in a `Frame` pad a little, and `bind` mouse click to a function in that padding that modifies `height` and `width` of the `Text` based on the mouse's relative position.

Comment: @Nae could you demonstrate in an answer?

Comment: This would be much easier to do using the ttk panedwindow and yield a more normal UI. The default handling of the sizegrip motion event is to amend the geometry of the toplevel widget. You would have to change that to amend the geometry management of your text widget explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this here is an example that uses `place` to manage the frame containing the text widget, scrollbar and sizegrip. If you remove the default bindings and supply new ones for the sizegrip then you can prevent it from changing the toplevel geometry and make it do something else.
Note that a paned window or two is the more normal UI design for this kind of thing.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        parent.wm_geometry("600x400")
        parent.wm_title(title)
        self.top = tk.Frame(self, height=100, background="green4")
        self.middle = tk.Frame(self, background="red4")
        self.lower = tk.Frame(self, height=100, background="blue4")

        self.textframe = ttk.Frame(self.middle)
        self.text = tk.Text(self.textframe)
        self.vs = ttk.Scrollbar(self.textframe,
                                command=self.text.yview)
        self.sg = ttk.Sizegrip(self.textframe)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vs.set)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        self.vs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="news")
        self.sg.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="sew")
        self.textframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.textframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.middle.bind('<Map>', self.Place)

        self.sg.bindtags((self.sg, '.','all'))
        self.sg.bind('<Button-1>', self.Press)
        self.sg.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.Drag)
        self.sg.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.Release)

        self.top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        self.middle.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news")
        self.lower.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="news")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="news")
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def Press(self, ev):
        self.dragging=True
        self.dragpos = (ev.x_root, ev.y_root)

    def Drag(self, ev):
        if self.dragging:
            dx = ev.x_root - self.dragpos[0]
            dy = ev.y_root - self.dragpos[1]
            sgx = self.sg.winfo_x() + dx
            sgy = self.sg.winfo_y() + dy
            sgw = self.sg.winfo_reqwidth()
            sgh = self.sg.winfo_reqheight()
            max_w = self.middle.winfo_width() - sgw
            max_h = self.middle.winfo_height() - sgh
            if sgx < 0 or sgx > max_w or sgy < 0 or sgy > max_h:
                return
            self.textframe.place(x=0, y=0,
                            width=sgx+sgw, height=sgy+sgh)
            self.dragpos = (ev.x_root, ev.y_root)

    def Release(self, ev):
        self.dragging=False

    def Place(self, ev):
        """Place the text widget controls once the rest of the
        application has been mapped so we actually have a size
        to work from.
        Reset the Map event to avoid re-calling this code."""
        self.textframe.bind('<Map>', None)
        self.textframe.place(x=0, y=0,
                             width=self.middle.winfo_width(),
                             height=self.middle.winfo_height())

def main(args=None):
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root, "Sizegrip demo")
    root.mainloop()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

The result:
[image: screenshot of the resulting UI]

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to mix place with grid in a tkinter app? Wouldn't it be possible to achieve the same goal only with the help of grid?

Comment: No. It is a problem to mix geometry managers for the same widget. Here the children of textframe are gridded and all the main frames (top,middle,lower) are gridded. But the child of the middle frame uses place exclusively. It is just necessary to avoid using grid on something else that is a child of middle.You might be able to use grid and manipulate the weight parameter for each cell to achieve a similar effect.